# RN error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build an archive for RN project, and I am facing this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-citzzdlmmmmsakbpzutdbpcewagt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJECT_NAME/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Braintree'
ld: library not found for -lBraintree
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried different things to fix this problem for example deleting the `podfile` & `podfilelock` then generate them again

and I followed all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/23539147/xcode-ld-Library-not-found-for-lpods) , but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

any clue what's the problem? or maybe solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution as well. I got this error after upgrading RN from 0.63.0 to 0.64.1. I followed RN upgrade helper and well, here I am... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ If I find an answer, I'll post it.

Comment: For me I deleted Xcode and install again and it worked